# Javascript : Why typeof() is returing boolean value as a string?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Maybe this question will look silly to you. But I have a quick one.

I'm learning **JavaScript** these days:

And trying to understand following code.

```js
var name = true; 
console.log(typeof(name));
```

why the output is `string` ?

I'm expecting output will be boolean type. Why its returning as a string ?

Comment: because `window.name` - look it up - check using almost any other var name, like Name for example ... window.name is speshul

Comment: rename the variable and check once. It's because of namespace

Comment: try something non generic: `var a = true; console.log(typeof(a))`

Comment: [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name).Why do starters start with obvious names? adding *"my"* to variable names fixes everything.

Comment: @Rajesh you got me... the output is ***boolean* this time... but it should behave in a same way with **name** variable right ?

Comment: @AdamAzad so you mean to say...**name** is reserved work** or something ?

Comment: @TusharNiras please read comments add by **Jaromanda**

Comment: @JaromandaX you answered it...!!  thanks! ;)

Comment: @TusharNiras, it's a reserved variable, and protected from overwriting. :)

Comment: @AdamAzad yes... Thanks brother !!...

Comment: @TusharNiras just a pointer. Always wrap your code in a function. variables defined outside any function becomes a part of global scope

Comment: @Rajesh Whoa! thanks for tip. I was not aware of it... ;)

Comment: Just to be clear: In browsers, `name` is a *predefined* global variable that converts any value that is assigned to it to a string. "Reserved (word)" as a very specific meaning when talking about programming languages, and `name` is not *reserved*. It doesn't have any meaning in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

typeof operator will give us the datatype of the variable in a string format.
for example:

```js
var a = false;
console.log(typeof a)
//Result: "boolean"

var b = {};
console.log(typeof b)
//Result: "object"


var name = true;
console.log(typeof name)
//Result: "string"
```

Every window having predefined variable called "name" and the datatype of this variable is "string". Open new window and in console just give name, it will give empty sting

Comment: This does not answer the question of why passing what looks like a Boolean outputs 'string'

Comment: that's right I guess... as @JaromandaX  said it's special variable may be ? and better not to use it.. :/

Comment: @TusharNiras—not a special variable or reserved word, it's a special property of the [*window* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window), which is synonymous with the global object in browsers. Other types of host don't necessarily have such restrictions, it's not part of ECMAScript.